# Creating an infrastructure hotspot using ubuntu 12.10

Tags: internet, android, hot-spot

I want to create an infrastructure hot-spot using ubuntu 12.10 as I want use internet on my android phone by creating an infrastructure hot-spot.I have tried to change the setting the hot-spot and make it infrastructure but it did not help and my android could not discover the hot-spot.........
Any help would be appreciated..........

Comment: Using an "ad-hoc" hotspot and network type "shared" didn't work? Seems to be working for me w/ various Android devices from 1.6 through 4.1...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ap-hotspot`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/raring/main/base/ap-hotspot) from the [`webupd8`](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8) repository to create an infrastracture AP instead of adhoc. I am using this on Ubuntu Precise (12.04), but it is available for Saucy, Raring and Quantal as well.

```
$ sudo su -
# add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
# aptitude update
# aptitude install ap-hotspot
# ap-hotspot configure
# ap-hotspot start
```

Some times the clients of this wifi do not get IP from dhcp. You can fix it by killing dnsmasq (it starts again automatically).

```
# killall dnsmasq
```

Comment: I found that my S3 couldn't get assigned an IP address.  I used `ifconfig` to check the address of the hotspot and assigned a static address to my phone based on that; it filled in the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 for me.

Comment: Sometimes you need to `killall dnsmasq` for the dhcp to work. I updated the answer.

Comment: Will this break any pre-existing uses of `dsnmasq`?

Comment: If you are using dnsmasq for its built-in ftp server, active transactions/sessions will be terminated. But for its DHCP and DNS services you are not breaking anything. (edit: by default the built-in ftp is not being used)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem while configuring hotspot on my android phone.
Following link was pretty helpful for me in this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381